# Google Chart: weekly schedule

Tags: google-visualization

Any suggestions on how I can use Google Chart API to display a weekly schedule? For example, a store's hours of operation:

- Sunday, 9am-5pm
- Monday, 9am-9pm
- Tuesday, 9am-9pm
- Wednesday, 9am-9pm
- Thursday, 9am-9pm
- Friday, 9am-12nn, 3pm-9pm
- Saturday, 9am-10pm

Looking for examples, code snippet, or general advice.

Comment: In which language ? also, What have you tried so far ?

Comment: PHP or JS. I'm not finding anything in the examples that make sense to me. Bar chart is the closest, I think. But not sure if it can represent something like Friday's schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stacked bar chart with two plots.

Hours on the Y axis.
Week days on the X axis.

First bar chart has start times.
Second bar chart has end times (minus start times).

The trick:  Make the color of the first bar chart the same as the chart background color so you can't see it.  Then, you'll just see the second bar chart.

I would start with 24 hour time first.  If you get that to work, you can replace the times with text labels (ie 2 PM).

Caveat:  I haven't tried this.

Comment: Do you have a photo of what you are talking about? I am new to Chart API.

Comment: No, the same technique could be used with any charting software...it's chart agnostic.